Different scrollback states of a single tmux session in two terminals?
I would like to attach to the same tmux session in two different terminals but have different scrollback states. For example in terminal 1 I would like to see the live output, while in terminal 2 I would like be scrolled much further back to see some earlier output.
I understand this could also be achieved by logging program output and then view that separately in a text editor, however that would forsake some niceties like text colouring, and also makes things trickey when it comes to consecutive program launches needing to switch the text editor to the latest version of the logs.
Alternatively is it possible to in a single terminal switch between scrollback and non-scrollback so I can look back and forth instead? I think such a command does in fact exist, but as the program outputs newlines I think this would "desync" how far scrolled back I am as that point is now further back in the history.

just a heads up: the thing about color is not correct. Some programs are aware of whether they are writing to a terminal or a file, and disable the color writing in the latter case. But most of them can be convinced to keep the color codes included, and then the output of less still is colorfull. So something like program --color=always | tee log.file | less +F for the "live" pane, and less --follow-name log.file for the "scrolling around" pane
